# What is the main site's background color?

Tags: discussion, design

I would like to use the main site's background color on my personal website.

#FFF, #000 and #EFF appear to be in the home page's source code. Thanks to [color-hex](http://www.color-hex.com/), I found those colors to be black, white and light blue respectively. I don't know anything about code except how to search through it by using Ctrl + F, so in addition, please tell me how to find the color value. Also, I am looking for the hex value.

Comment: By the way, a straightforward way to find out such things is to take a screenshot and use the colour-picker tool from your favourite graphics software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **#fbf8f3**. From the [style sheet](http://cdn.sstatic.net/academia/all.css?v=a1c833099250):

```
html,body{… background:#fbf8f3; …}
```

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why it didn't come up when I searched for it...

Comment: Thanks, I was too lazy to do this. Wondering why its in disagreement from the tool, though...

Answer (score 0):

Using the Digital Color Meter utility, the RGB values are as `(25,246,240)` (see image below), which translates into `#FAF6F0`.

[image]

Comment: Which is interesting since it doesn't agree with the other answer.

Comment: @StrongBad: Not really. Different colour spaces; these are not sRGB values. And even if you asked the Digital Color Meter to show the sRGB values, you won't (necessarily) get the right value. (Instead you get something like the closest approximation of the original sRGB values converted to some native colour space and then back to sRGB, with roundoff errors and possibly some clipping.)